# how to accept the connection only confirmed users on symfony?

Tags: database, authentication, symfony, security

I have an "isConfirmed" attribute in my User entity.
And if isConfirmed == false, I want the connection denied.
It is up to the backoffice to validate or not the users.
I tried to implement the logic in the authenticate() method of loginformauthenticator, but the code is not taken into account at all. I can connect even if isConfirmed == false.
And I noticed that even removing all the content (and doing php bin/console cache:clear) of the authenticate method, I can login!

My authenticate method:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
     {

         $loginData = $request->request->get('login');
         $email = $loginData['email'];
         $password = $loginData['password'];

         $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

         if (!$user->isIsConfirmed()) {
             throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Account is not confirmed');
         }

         return new Passport(
             new UserBadge($email),
             new PasswordCredentials($password)
         );
     }
```

I used to use "dd()" but the dd is not taken into account since the content of authenticate does not seem to be executed...

Comment: You should use a custom User Checker, take a look at documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html

Comment: @VincentDecaux merci ! I made an uservaladationchecker that implements usercheckerinterface and it worked :)